# basic recursion in java

Tags: java, recursion

Two small questions regarding recursion in java.

```
public int recursiveFunc(int n) {
    if (n==0)
        return(1);
    else
        return( recursiveFunc(n -1) + 1 );
}
```

If recursiveFunc(150) is called, the answer should be 151. Could someone please explain to me how it gets this answer / what steps does it take?

Same again for the following function assuming recursiveFunc2(17), what would the answer be and how? Thanks.

```
public int recursiveFunc2(int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return(0);
    else
        return( recursiveFunc2(n/2)+1 );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you replace:

```
return( recursiveFunc(n1) + 1 );
```

with:

```
return recursiveFunc(n - 1) + 1 ;
```

it works as expected.

For the second functions, it's a bit more interesting. Think how many times you can divide 17 by 2 until you reach 0 (recursion stop condition)? It's a bit trickier, but analyze the steps:

```
recursiveFunc2(17) = 
recursiveFunc2(8) + 1 = 
recursiveFunc2(4) + 1 + 1 = 
recursiveFunc2(2) + 1 + 1 + 1 = 
recursiveFunc2(1) + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 
recursiveFunc2(0) + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 
                0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5
```

Comment: Note that when dividing by 2 with integers, the result is floored, and so this is not that many times (in the given setup) - was not sure if you were implying an infinite amount as would be expected with real numbers.

Comment: @TravisJ: that's right, I included sample evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

When analyzing recursion you must examine the base case to get to the end result. In this setup, the base case is

```
if (n == 0)
    return(0);
```

So you can reverse engineer back from there and then built up to the entrance case. In your example, the entrance is when `n = 150`.

**Base Case**

`recursiveFunc(0)` is called. The base case is hit in that `n == 0` and `1` is returned.

**Build Up**

`1` is returned to the previous call which would have been

```
return recursiveFunc( n - 1 ) + 1;//note that n was 1 to produce a call of 0
```

Thus, `recursiveFunc( 1 - 1 )` becomes 1 and that line looks more like

```
return 1 + 1;
```

**Continue**

Backing this up further, the next call would be where that returns `2` to. Now, there should be a pattern evident. Namely, that

```
A0 = 1;
A1 = A0 + 1;
A2 = A1 + 1;
...
An = A(n-1) + 1;
...
An = n + 1;
```

So this is how you can come to the conclusion that A150 = 151, or more explicitly, that `recursiveFunc(150) == 151`.